# MPI strange increment of normal int

Tags: c, macos, process, mpi

I'm programming in with MPI library in C at the moment and I have the following snippet of code that behaves very strange.

This is **not** a minimal reproducible example, but I think there is an obvious problem with the code snippet, even unrelated to mpi, which can be easily solved without reproduction. Do let me know if there is additional code that needed and I happily provide it!

```c
void monitor_proposals(int people_per_gender) {
    int satisfied_women = 0;
    /* declarations independent of the one above (omitted) */

    while (satisfied_women < people_per_gender) {
        MPI_Recv(&buf, sizeof(buf), MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        sender = status.MPI_SOURCE;
        index = sender/2;
        printf("here\n");
        printf("ppg=%d, sw=%d\n", people_per_gender, satisfied_women);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (women_atleast_one_proposal[index] == 0) {
            women_atleast_one_proposal[index] = sender+1; /* logical id */
            satisfied_women += 1;
            printf("Monitor: First proposal to woman (%d)\n", sender+1);
            printf("ppg=%d, sw=%d\n", people_per_gender, satisfied_women);
        }
        if (satisfied_women == people_per_gender) {
            MPI_Send(&DONE, sizeof(DONE), MPI_INT, sender, sender, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("this\n");
        } else {
            MPI_Send(&NOT_DONE, sizeof(NOT_DONE), MPI_INT, sender, sender, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("that\n");
        }
    }
    printf("outside\n");
}
```

Output in terminal:

```
here
ppg=1, sw=16
Monitor: First proposal to woman (1)
ppg=1, sw=17
that
```

My expectation is of course that `satisfied_women` is initialized to 0, then incremented to 1 and therefore will break the loop once it iterates. I also flush the output stream to stdout which should show me if there is uncontrolled looping but there seems not to be.

Expected output:

```
here
ppg=1, sw=0
Monitor: First proposal to woman (1)
ppg=1, sw=1
this
outside
```

I'm using `mpich: stable 4.0.1` via homebrew.

**EDIT**
I solved the increment problem and this is the code right now, I (changed `count` argument to 1 in several places so that part works now).

There are n men processes and n women processes. Men and women rate eachother. Men propose to women by sending and women wait for proposals. If a woman receives a better rated man than the currently accepted, then the previous man will have to propose to another woman.

There is a monitoring process that is called once every iteration in women's `while`-loop, and it feeds back to the sending woman if it should exit or not. When woman exit the `while`-loop they notified the man that it accepted most recently.

```c
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef enum gender {
    MAN,
    WOMAN
} gender_t;

/* men use array of women and fill in each womens rating_t, and vice versa */
typedef struct rating {
    gender_t gender;
    int id;
    int rating;
} rating_t;

/*******************************************************************************************
 * HELPER FUNCTIONS ************************************************************************
 *******************************************************************************************/

/* custom compare for qsort */
int compare(const void *r1, const void *r2) {
    return ((rating_t*)r1)->rating > ((rating_t*)r2)->rating ? -1 : 1;
}

/* random shuffling of ratings */
void shuffle_ratings(rating_t *profiles, int size) {
    int random_index, temp;
    for (int max_index = size-1; max_index > 0; max_index--) {
        random_index = rand() % (max_index+1);
        /* swap values at indexes */
        temp = profiles[max_index].rating;
        profiles[max_index].rating = profiles[random_index].rating;
        profiles[random_index].rating = temp;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************************
 * PROCESSES *******************************************************************************
 *******************************************************************************************/ 

/* keeps track of women who are with a man, eventually notifies them it's done */
void monitor_proposals(int people_per_gender) {
    MPI_Status status;
    const int DONE = 1;
    const int NOT_DONE = 0;
    int *women_atleast_one_proposal = (int*)calloc(people_per_gender, sizeof(int));
    int satisfied_women = 0;
    int sender, index;
    int buf; /* not useful */

    while (satisfied_women < people_per_gender) {
        MPI_Recv(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        sender = status.MPI_SOURCE;
        index = sender/2;
        fflush(stdout);
        if (women_atleast_one_proposal[index] == 0) {
            women_atleast_one_proposal[index] = sender+1; /* logical id */
            satisfied_women++;
            printf("Monitor: First proposal to woman (%d)\n", sender+1);
            printf("ppg=%d, sw=%d\n", people_per_gender, satisfied_women);
        }
        if (satisfied_women == people_per_gender) {
            MPI_Send(&DONE, 1, MPI_INT, sender, sender, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("this\n");
        } else {
            MPI_Send(&NOT_DONE, 1, MPI_INT, sender, sender, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("that\n");
        }
    }
}

/* function for men, highest rating is proposed to first */
void propose(int id, rating_t *my_ratings) {
    MPI_Status rec_status;
    int proposals = 0;
    int accepted = 0;
    int propose_dest, propose_rating;

    while (!accepted) {
        propose_dest = my_ratings[proposals].id - 1;
        propose_rating = my_ratings[proposals].rating;
        printf("Man (%d): Proposed to woman (%d) who's rated %d\n", id, propose_dest+1, propose_rating);
        fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Send(&propose_rating, 1, MPI_INT, propose_dest, propose_dest, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        proposals++;
        MPI_Recv(&accepted, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rec_status);
    }
    printf("man %d accepted\n", id);
}

/* function for women, accepts first proposal but can replace */
void receive_proposals(int id, rating_t *my_ratings, int monitor_rank) {
    MPI_Status status;

    const int ACCEPT = 1;
    const int REJECT = 0;
    int DONT_CARE = 0;
    int monitor_response;
    int from_man;

    int received_man_rank = -1;
    int received_man_rating = -1;
    int best_man_rank = -1;
    int best_man_rating = -1;

    while (1) {
        MPI_Recv(&from_man, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        received_man_rank = status.MPI_SOURCE;
        received_man_rating = my_ratings[received_man_rank/2].rating;
        
        if (best_man_rank == -1) { /* first proposal received */
            best_man_rank = received_man_rank;
            best_man_rating = received_man_rating;
            printf("Woman (%d): Accepted man (%d) #%d#\n", id, best_man_rank+1, best_man_rating);
        } else if (received_man_rating > best_man_rating) { /* proposal is better rated than current accepted, notify replaced */
            MPI_Send(&REJECT, 1, MPI_INT, best_man_rank, best_man_rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("Woman (%d): Replaced man (%d) #%d# for man (%d) #%d#\n", id, best_man_rank+1, \
                    best_man_rating, received_man_rank+1, received_man_rating);
            best_man_rank = received_man_rank;
            best_man_rating = received_man_rating;
        } else { /* notify denied man */
            MPI_Send(&REJECT, 1, MPI_INT, received_man_rank, received_man_rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("Woman (%d): Rejected proposing man (%d) #%d# due to best man (%d) #%d#\n", id, received_man_rank+1, \
                    received_man_rating, best_man_rank+1, best_man_rating);
        }

        MPI_Send(&DONT_CARE, 1, MPI_INT, monitor_rank, monitor_rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&monitor_response, 1, MPI_INT, monitor_rank, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        if (monitor_response) {
            printf("woman here\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    /* send ok to accepted man */
    MPI_Send(&ACCEPT, 1, MPI_INT, best_man_rank, best_man_rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Woman (%d) + Man (%d) MARRIED\n", id, best_man_rank+1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pool_size, people_per_gender;

    int rank, id, monitor_rank;
    rating_t *my_ratings;
    gender_t gender;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pool_size);
    
    if (pool_size % 2 != 1) {
        if (rank == 0) 
            printf("Requirement: men == women and 1 extra process!\n");
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }

    people_per_gender = pool_size / 2;                                          /* number of men/women */
    id = rank + 1;                                                              /* logical id */
    monitor_rank = pool_size - 1;                                               /* collecting of proposals */

    if (rank != monitor_rank) {
        gender = (id % 2 == 0 ? MAN : WOMAN);                                   /* odd id - woman, even id - man */
        my_ratings = (rating_t*)malloc(people_per_gender * sizeof(rating_t));   /* rate half of pool, i.e. other gender */

        /* create "profiles" of other gender */
        for (int i = 0; i < people_per_gender; i++) {
            my_ratings[i].gender = (gender == MAN ? WOMAN : MAN);
            my_ratings[i].id = ( gender == MAN ? (2*i+1) : (2*i+2) );
            my_ratings[i].rating = i+1;
        }

        /* randomize ratings of other gender */
        srand(time(NULL) + id);
        shuffle_ratings(my_ratings, people_per_gender);
        qsort(my_ratings, people_per_gender, sizeof(rating_t), compare);

        if (gender == WOMAN)    printf("W(%d) ratings: ", id);
        else if (gender == MAN) printf("M(%d) ratings: ", id);

        for (int i = 0; i < people_per_gender; i++) 
            printf("| {id:%d, %d} | ", my_ratings[i].id, my_ratings[i].rating);
        printf("\n");
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == monitor_rank) printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /* call function based on process type */
    if (rank == monitor_rank) {
        monitor_proposals(people_per_gender);
    } else {
        if (gender == WOMAN) 
            receive_proposals(id, my_ratings, monitor_rank);
        else if (gender == MAN)
            propose(id, my_ratings);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("ID (%d): Done\n", id);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `MPI_xxx(..., sizeof(...), MPI_INT, ...)` looks fishy

Comment: Indeed it does. I tried sending `1` instead of sizeof(int), but got an error along the lines "received 4 bytes but receiving buffer is 16" and if I changed to `2`it was instead "received 8 bytes but receiving buffer is 16". I even read the doc's and it said the the argument should  be the count of MPI_Datatype (in this case MPI_INT) to send so I got really confused.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the error come from? From a MPI point of view, it is perfectly legal to declare a 16 bytes buffer, post a receive of 8 bytes and being sent only 4 bytes. But you cannot post a receive of 4 bytes (regardless the buffer size) and be sent 16 bytes.

Comment: `Abort(200941582) on node 4 (rank 4 in comm 0): Fatal error in internal_Recv: Message truncated, error stack:
internal_Recv(127).......: MPI_Recv(buf=0x7ff7bdb72578, count=1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x7ff7bdb72598) failed
MPIDIG_recv_type_init(72): Message from rank 0 and tag 2 truncated; 4 bytes received but buffer size is 16`

Comment: I interpreted it as too few bytes being sent, but in case you can clarify  that it's something else be my guest! I saw online that this error was often portraited as `20 bytes received but buffer size is 10` or something. Basically too large send size.

Comment: we both read it the other way around :-) 16 bytes were sent, but `MPI_Recv()` can only accept 4, and this is a fatal error according to the standard.

Comment: Well in that case I must say that the error response is a little strange?

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving us enough code. How is the buffer defined in:

`MPI_Recv(&buf, sizeof(buf), MPI_INT,`

1. `int buf` then this is almost correct because `sizeof` will give 4.
2. `int buf[20]` then `sizeof` will give the sizes in bytes, not in ints.
3. `buf = (int*)malloc(whatever)` then `sizeof` will give 8 bytes for the pointer.

In other words, it's definitely wrong, but precisely how we can not tell.

Comment: `int buf` simply, check my other reply for more details.

Comment: Your `sizeof` is the wrong thing to use, no matter how you define `buf`.

Comment: So, in what way, can I correctly use `int buf` and `MPI_INT` in this implementation? As I said I read documentation and wanted to write 1 initially and sizeof(...) is simply a workaround that adds up, therefore I'd like concrete suggestions.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that this is affecting my initial problem of random value of women_satisfied? Is it because of UB from MPI_Recv?

Comment: You're not giving us enough code to understand what you're doing. In your `while` loop you first do a receive then a send. So there has to be another process that is doing the initial send but I don't have that code.

Comment: Added my full code now and also briefly explained it, see edit on original post.